# Удаление элемента при наведении JQuery

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть фотогалерея на сайте. Фотки выводятся с каталога при помощи PHP. Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на фото появлялся крестик, при клике на котором отправлялся AJAX запрос на удаление PHP-скрипту? (Хочу примерно как в фотогалереи ВКонтакте).

Comment: @Макс Ковалько плохо что вы даже теоретически не представляете себе код реализации своей задумки, очень плохо!

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так...

```
<style>
  .close-image {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  } 
  .image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .image:hover .close-image {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<div class="image" id="1">
  <div class="close-image"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.close-image').click(function() {
      $.post('yoursite.com', {
          imageId: $(this).parent().attr('id')
      }, function() {
          console.log('image deleted');
      });
  });
</script>
```